# (Ember.js) Assertion Failed: You specified the templateName icon for <(subclass of ClassName.Button) : ember353>, but it did not exist

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am upgrading a web application from a prerelease of Ember.js to 1.0.0 and I get the title error.  It is showing up 9 different times.  I specify the templateName fairly often in subclasses (more than 9 different times).

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Like the message say you need to have a template called `icon`.
Try to include the following in your html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="icon">
  Hello
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix anything

Comment: What causes this error to be thrown for some specifications of templateName but not others? (many define "icon" as the templateName but only a few errors are thrown)